# Perl: Extracting begin and End date for timestamps

Tags: perl, text, timestamp

Need help to extract begin & end of date in below date & timestamps list
let say I have below timestamps data extracted from log file and need to extract only begin & end for each date & time .
The output will be use for time difference between begin to end calculation.

**Data** 
2021-Oct-11 16:27:39
2021-Oct-11 16:28:10
2021-Oct-11 16:30:47
2021-Oct-11 16:30:47
2021-Oct-12 09:27:03 
2021-Oct-12 10:27:03  
2021-Oct-12 18:22:15 
2021-Oct-13 08:57:16 
2021-Oct-13 08:57:37
2021-Oct-13 11:33:25
2021-Oct-13 11:33:25 
2021-Nov-08 16:45:17 
2021-Nov-08 16:49:10
2021-Nov-08 17:00:50
2021-Nov-08 22:10:24 
2021-Nov-09 11:51:35 
2021-Nov-09 11:52:40
2021-Nov-09 12:14:39
2021-Nov-09 14:23:10 
...
...
...

**expected Output**
begin : 2021-Oct-11 16:27:39 
end   :2021-Oct-11 16:30:47 
begin : 2021-Oct-12 09:27:03 
end   :2021-Oct-12 18:22:15 
begin :2021-Oct-13 08:57:16 
end   :2021-Oct-13 11:33:25
begin :2021-Nov-08 16:45:17 
end   :2021-Nov-08 22:10:24 
begin :2021-Nov-09 11:51:35
end   :2021-Nov-09 14:23:10

below are my script, but I only managed to extracted the begin data only

```
%key;
     while ( <IN> ) {
              $_=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; 
              my ($saved_date, $record_date);
              chomp ;
              my ($k, $d) = split;
               
                if (! exists $key{ $k } ) {
                    $key{ $k } = $d;
                    my ($dtformat) = $d =$dtformat;
                    $end_date = Time::Piece->strptime($_, $dtformat);
                    next;
                    
                    my ($dtformat) = $key{ $k } = $dtformat;
                    $saved_date = Time::Piece->strptime($_, $dtformat);
    
                    my ($dtformat) = $d =$dtformat;
                    $record_date = Time::Piece->strptime($_, $dtformat);
                    
                    if ( $record_date - $saved_date > 0 ) {
                       $key{ $k } = $d;
                    }
                }   
        }#endofwhile
        for ( sort keys %key ) {
             print "begin: ", $_, " ",$key{ $_ },"\n"; 

        }
```

**Output**
begin: 2021-Nov-08 16:45:17
begin: 2021-Nov-09 11:51:35
begin: 2021-Oct-10 21:59:39
begin: 2021-Oct-11 00:21:46
begin: 2021-Oct-12 09:27:03
begin: 2021-Oct-13 08:57:16 
begin: 2021-Sep-30 00:21:23

need help how to get the "end" part

thanks

Comment: Is your data already sorted like in your example?

Comment: yes, its sorted  same as my example.

Comment: What differentiates a start timestamp from an end timestamp?

Comment: differentiates by time . as example begin :2021-Nov-09 11:51:35 &
end :2021-Nov-09 14:23:10

Comment: Not clear what is the difference between 2021-Nov-09 11:51:35 and 2021-Nov-09 14:23:10. You mean first time and last time for a given day?

Comment: Oh, I think it's the earliest and latest timestamp for a day.

Comment: Removed the unnecessary "Windows" tag. Corrected "PERL" to "Perl" in question title.

Comment: Tip: _always_ add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the beginning of your Perl scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The secret is in the data structure you've used to store your data. As you're interested in the first and last timestamps for a day, I've built a hash keyed on the date where the value is an array containing all of the timestamps for that day. We can then sort the timestamps for each day and easily extract the earliest and latest ones.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

# The hash where we'll store our data
my %dates;
# The format of our dates
my $date_format = '%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S';

# Read each data item from DATA (or wherever)
while (<DATA>) {
  # Remove the newline
  chomp;

  # Parse the string into a Time::Piece object
  my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($_, $date_format);

  # Store the object in our hash of arrays
  push @{$dates{$date->ymd}}, $date;
}

# Get the list of hash keys sorted by date.
for (sort keys %dates) {
  # For each date key...
  # Get the sorted list of dates into an array...
  my @times = sort { $a->hms cmp $b->hms } @{ $dates{$_} };

  # And print the first and last elements of the array,
  # using the correct format string.
  say "begin: ", $times[0]->strftime($date_format);
  say "end: ", $times[-1]->strftime($date_format);
}

__DATA__
2021-Oct-11 16:27:39
2021-Oct-11 16:28:10
2021-Oct-11 16:30:47
2021-Oct-11 16:30:47
2021-Oct-12 09:27:03
2021-Oct-12 10:27:03
2021-Oct-12 18:22:15
2021-Oct-13 08:57:16
2021-Oct-13 08:57:37
2021-Oct-13 11:33:25
2021-Oct-13 11:33:25
2021-Nov-08 16:45:17
2021-Nov-08 16:49:10
2021-Nov-08 17:00:50
2021-Nov-08 22:10:24
2021-Nov-09 11:51:35
2021-Nov-09 11:52:40
2021-Nov-09 12:14:39
2021-Nov-09 14:23:10
```

Comment: For the `sort`, you probably meant `$a->hms cmp $b->hms` (instead of `->ymd`). Although you can omit the `sort` altogether since the input dates are already sorted. I don't know which one you prefer, so I'll let you edit ;-)

Comment: @Dada: Thanks, fixed. I prefer to keep the explicit sort as data is often not as pre-sorted as the users think it is :-)

Comment: let say if  I want to print all array content between begin : $times[0] to end : $times[-1], how to write it?

Comment: @mrJa: If you have a new question, then it's best to ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Since the input is sorted, all you need is this:

```perl
my ( $prev_line, $prev_d );

while ( my $line = <> ) {
   my ( $d ) = split( ' ', $line );
   if ( !$prev_line ) {
      print "begin: $line";
      $prev_d = $d;
   }
   elsif ( $d ne $prev_d  ) {
      print "end: $prev_line";
      print "begin: $line";
      $prev_d = $d;
   }

   $prev_line = $line;
}

if ( $prev_line ) {
   print "end: $prev_line";
}
```